# How to model two parabolic peaks of different magnitudes and inclines using a single polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

I recently came upon a graph of two parabolic curves of different magnitudes and intensities and attempted to model it with a single parabolic equation. [Rough graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Thk.png)
I have the coordinates of the vertices: (3, 667), (8, 1287). I have a few other points as well: (1, 55), (2, 187), (4, 188), (5, 86), (6, 120), (7, 375), (9, 13).

I was wondering if there was a systematic way to go about creating this equation.

My first thought was to transform the graph several units down and find the x-intercepts after doing so, then write the equation in factored form {y = -a(x-x_i)(x-x_ii)...). For instance, I transformed the graph 600 units down, found the x-ints to be 2.86, 3.14, 7.25, 8.75. I used the desmos online calculator and tried a few a-values, settling for a= 15, and by finagling the x-intercept values, could more closely align the graph with the original data points.

The equation I settled on was -15(x-2.56)(x-3.34)(x-6.83)(x-9.27)+600. However, I was wondering if there was a more streamlined way to get to an equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions are as follows:

1. Find more coordinates on the graph
2. Plot the points corresponding to these coordinates on [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en).
3. Use the [FitPoly](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/FitPoly_Command) method to find the best polynomial approximation for the given points. This method will computationally minimise the [sum of the squares of the residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) to give the best match for the points.

Using the coordinates provided in the question, the equation I got using the above method (for a polynomial of degree $7$) was $f(x) \approx -0.97x^{7}+33.81x^{6}-483.50x^{5}+3643.69x^{4}-15411.56x^{3}+35825.7x^{2}-41137.97x+17585.8$ but there is scope for much better approximations using more points.